# How to show a default value in the view if a data field is empty, in angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the best way to show a placeholder value in the view when a data field is blank, in Angular.JS?

For Example if `vm.text` is empty, I want it to display `- - -` in the view. If it is not empty, then show the value of `vm.text`:

**Option 1**, I know I could accomplish this through using the `ng-show` property:

```
<div>
    <span ng-show="!vm.text">- - -</span>
    <span ng-show="vm.text">{{ vm.text }}</span>
</div>
```

**Option 2**, in the controller, I could set the value of `vm.text` to be `"- - -"` instead of resetting it to `""`:

```
 // reset field
 vm.text = "- - -";
```

Is there another, simpler way to do this in Angular.JS that I don't know about?

Comment: <span> {{ vm.text ? vm.text : '---'}} </span>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do :

```
<div>
    <span>{{ vm.text || '- - -' }}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't like having lots of logic in my view.

To simplify things I would recommend implementing some logic in your controller/service that sets vm.text to `'- - -'` if it is not assigned.

Does this make sense?

Then keep the front-end clean and simple

```
<div>
    <span>{{ vm.text }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, and I agree with you about keeping lots of logic out of the view. However, the '- - - -' is just placeholder text meant only for the view, not to be stored in the database. So that's why I thought it might be a case that the logic should be handled in the view, I just didn't know the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ternary operator.

```
<span>{{ vm.text === '' ? '- - -' : vm.text }}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register a `filter`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$filterProvider#register

```
yourModule.filter('defValue', function(){
    return function(input){
        if(!input) return "---";
    };
});

<span>{{vm.text | defValue}}</span>
```